# SQL Server 2016 Evaluation and Dynamic Data Mask

Tags: sql-server-2016, data-masking

I would like to try out the dynamic data mask to see if it will actually fit our needs.  I have downloaded the Evaluation edition -

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)   Apr 29 2016 23:23:58   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit)

I have turned on trace flags 209 and 219; yet still cannot mask the data.

Does this functionality not work in the eval edition or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about eval, but it should work.  Using SSMS 2016 with the WideWorldImporters db, you have to define a mask on the column, then query as a user who does not have permissions to unmask the data.  Here is a sample query again using SSMS 2016 and WWI:

```
ALTER TABLE [Sales].[Orders]
ALTER COLUMN [ContactPersonID] ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'random(1,12)');  

SELECT TOP 1000 [OrderID]
      ,[CustomerID]
      ,[SalespersonPersonID]
      ,[PickedByPersonID]
      ,[ContactPersonID]
      ,[BackorderOrderID]
      ,[OrderDate]
      ,[ExpectedDeliveryDate]
      ,[CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber]
      ,[IsUndersupplyBackordered]
      ,[Comments]
      ,[DeliveryInstructions]
      ,[InternalComments]
      ,[PickingCompletedWhen]
      ,[LastEditedBy]
      ,[LastEditedWhen]
  FROM [WideWorldImporters].[Sales].[Orders]

CREATE USER TestUser WITHOUT LOGIN;  
GRANT SELECT ON [WideWorldImporters].[Sales].[Orders] TO TestUser;  

EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestUser';  
SELECT * FROM [WideWorldImporters].[Sales].[Orders]
REVERT;
```